# Recover Ubuntu 20.04 after failed upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, data-recovery

On my laptop I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot and, after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 failed, Windows is the only system I am able to boot and grub is not available.
This is not a big issue however because I can use Windows recovery to boot other OS installed or USB

From Windows recovery menu I see two version of Ubuntu available

- Ubuntu 18.04 which I am able to boot, in standard or recovery mode;
- A second Ubuntu version which I suppose is 20.04. This does not boot in standard way nor in recovery mode.

What I would like to do is recover my Ubuntu 20.04 possibly without reinstalling it.
I know there is an option to reinstall the system without losing data and apps but this would format Windows partition if I am not wrong.

I tried using the recovery mode as described here [Fixing a failed upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in recovery mode](https://koen.vervloesem.eu/blog/fixing-a-failed-upgrade-to-ubuntu-2204-lts-in-recovery-mode/) and here [LiveCdRecovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)

The problem is the recovery mode does not work for Ubuntu 20.04, not even using the USB. From here when I press Ctrl-Alt-F1 and log in, my credentials are not recognized.
I am not sure if I can use the recovery mode of Ubuntu 18.04 to recover the 20.04.

What would be the best option I have?

Comment: A failed upgrade is a corrupted install. Recovering from this is a reinstall. You can not use one version of Ubuntu to recover a corrupted install of another version. Sorry this is a reinstall situation.